# List Preference and Shared Preferences

Tags: android

When and How do you use the ListPreferences? Is it an alternate for ListActivity, listView?

How do you decide whether this is the better choice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it's name says List Preferences are used to store Preferences. I use for example to choose the car color of my buddies. This will be saved to shared preferences.

List Preference needs to go in a PreferenceActivity, so that should only be Settings, that's how is advised. A ListPreference is a 1 row display in Preference Activity and will open up the choices to select from.

ListViews are used for much more, and is intended for all use except settings/preferences. If you want your users to navigate on the list and choose one and see some screen coming up on that info you need ListView.